# Шаблоны WORD

Tags: php, ms-word, шаблоны

Подскажите как добавить поля в WORD для ввода информации через PHP.

Я использую PHPWord. Пытаюсь записать значение поля через

```
$PHPWord = new PHPWord();
$document = $PHPWord->loadTemplate('/1.docx');
$document->setValue('Value1', '123');
$writer = PHPWord_IOFactory::createWriter($PHPWord, "Word2007");
$writer->save('2.docx');
```

Проблема в том, что я не уверен в правильности добавления полей в WORD. Как правильно их добавлять?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел ответ на свой вопрос самостоятельно :)

В документе WORD нужно просто написать ${Value1}.

Код нужно поправить следующим образом:

```
$PHPWord = new PHPWord();
$document = $PHPWord->loadTemplate('/1.docx');
$document->setValue('Value1', '123');
$document->save('2.docx');
```